# lxc-start: Invalid argument - failed to clone

Tags: docker, lxc

Complete newbie trying to get my feet wet on docker, so maybe I am doing something obviously wrong. I am having trouble running a container:

```
root@tethys:~# docker run ubuntu ls
lxc-start: Invalid argument - failed to clone

lxc-start: failed to create vethNGY9xv-veth3eKuyS : Operation not supported
lxc-start: failed to create netdev
lxc-start: failed to create the network
lxc-start: failed to spawn '38e59da80ff79f024304c761704924172fbd7632be705f9b71659a91de8467e9'
lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to remove cgroup '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/38e59da80ff79f024304c761704924172fbd7632be705f9b71659a91de8467e9'
```

Everything seems properly installed:

```
root@tethys:~# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
learn/tutorial      latest              8dbd9e392a96        8 months ago        128 MB
ubuntu              12.04               8dbd9e392a96        8 months ago        128 MB
ubuntu              latest              8dbd9e392a96        8 months ago        128 MB
ubuntu              precise             8dbd9e392a96        8 months ago        128 MB
ubuntu              12.10               b750fe79269d        8 months ago        175.3 MB
ubuntu              quantal             b750fe79269d        8 months ago        175.3 MB
```

The docker version is the currently stable version (actually, committed six days ago):

```
root@tethys:~# docker version
Client version: 0.7.1
Go version (client): go1.2
Git commit (client): 88df052
Server version: 0.7.1
Git commit (server): 88df052
Go version (server): go1.2
Last stable version: 0.7.1
```

And I would say my system should be supported:

```
root@tethys:~# uname -a
Linux tethys.wavilon.net 2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Thu Aug 25 16:40:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@tethys:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

What else could I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-precise-12-04-lts-64-bit), docker "works best on the 3.8 kernel."

Comment: I have the very same issue with Docker 0.8.0, Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and kernel 3.8.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64

Comment: It looks like the common point is the use of GRSEC. Is there anything in the kernel logs or security logs?

Comment: @azmeuk try running `lxc-checkconfig` (part of the lxc package) and see if it complains about any missing kernel features/permissions.

Comment: @lnmx some features seem to miss, but how can I enable them ? If possible, without rebooting my production server :) https://gist.github.com/azmeuk/8859316

Answer (score 0):

For a grsecurity kernel especially if you are trying to run 'unprivileged containers' in LXC you will need to set the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_caps = 0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_chmod = 0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_pivot = 0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_chroot = 0
kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_mount = 0
```

& then `sysctl -p`